# Can I use Tensorflow XLA with Tflite model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

As in the title, can I use XLA compilation with TF lite models - according to the documentation: `TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_auto_jit=2 path/to/your/tf/program`, so can I use it with e.g. `benchmark_model` from this site: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement ?

Answer (score 2):

No. The TensorFlow Lite code and relevant benchmark does not support / use XLA in anyway now. Adding the flag has no effect.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? Why?

Comment: I can see on page https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/benchmark that with benchmark_model I can run model in pb format. Is this possible to use XLA with pb model?

Comment: The tool you pointed to is running TensorFlow. TensorFlow uses GraphDef (in ProtoBuf/PB format).

TensorFlow Lite uses TensorFlow Lite model format (in FlatBuffer serialization format). 

These 2 execution runtimes are very disjoint. You won't be able to use TFLite with GraphDef (PB) model.